# Prove that $5x^2−2xy−8x+ 2y^2−2y+ 5 \ge 0$ for all $x, y\in\mathbb R$. When does equality occur?

Tags: inequality, polynomials, roots

I tried grouping the $x$'s and the $y$'s but that didn't get me anywhere. I know that $5x^2, 2y^2$, and $5$ are always positive. I am not sure what to try next.

Comment: @HaiDangel29 One of the possible solutions involving discriminant doesn't mean the question needs to be tagged (discriminant)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By inspection, equality occurs for $x=y=1$.

So the obvious choice is to group around these values. This also gives a somewhat more detailed explanation how you arrive at these magic squares:

$$
5x^2−2xy−8x+ 2y^2−2y+ 5 = \\
5((x-1) +1)^2−2((x-1)+1)((y-1) + 1)−8(x-1)+ 2((y-1)+1)^2−2(y-1) -5\\
= 5(x-1)^2  - 2(x-1)(y-1)  +2(y-1)^2 =\\
= 4(x-1)^2  + ((x-1)-(y-1))^2  +(y-1)^2 = \\
= 4(x-1)^2  + (x-y)^2  +(y-1)^2 \\
\geq 0
$$
which is clear.

Answer (score 5):

Bit late to the party. A sort of minimalist expression  is
$$  \frac{1}{5}(5x-y-4)^2 + \frac{9}{5} (y-1)^2  $$
so  we get zero only when $y=1$ and $5x-1-4 =0,$ so also $x=1.$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 4 }{ 5 }  &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 9 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 4 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 &  - 1 &  - 4 \\ 
 - 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 4 &  - 1 & 5 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

for the curious, there is an algorithm for symmetric matrices:

Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 &  - 1 &  - 4 \\ 
 - 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 4 &  - 1 & 5 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 &  - 1 &  - 4 \\ 
 - 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 4 &  - 1 & 5 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 &  - 4 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 9 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 9 }{ 5 }  \\ 
 - 4 &  -  \frac{ 9 }{ 5 }  & 5 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 4 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 4 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 9 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 9 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 9 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 9 }{ 5 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 4 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 9 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 &  - 1 &  - 4 \\ 
 - 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 4 &  - 1 & 5 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 9 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 4 }{ 5 }  &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 9 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 4 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 &  - 1 &  - 4 \\ 
 - 1 & 2 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 4 &  - 1 & 5 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: very elaborated, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

take the expression $$5x^{2}-2xy-8x+2y^{2}-2y+5$$ we want to write this as a sum of squares somehow. grouping the terms as:
$$(x^{2}-2xy+y^{2}) + (y^{2}-2y+1) + (4x^{2}-8x+4) $$
factoring the three expressions gives
$$(x-y)^{2} + (y-1)^{2} + 4(x-1)^{2}$$ which is the sum of squares, each of which is greater than $0$.
for equality to hold, notice that both $(y-1)^{2}$ and $4(x-1)^{2}$ have roots of 1 which means they will be zero at that value, and also notice that $(x-y)^{2}$ will be zero whenever $x=y$, this means that we should take $x=y=1$ for equality to hold

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

$5x^2-2xy-8x+2y^2-2y+5=x^2-2xy+y^2+4x^2-8x+4+y^2-2y+1=(x-y)^2+(2x-2)^2+(y-1)^2$

Comment: So equality happens iff $x=y=1$.

Answer (score 2):

The LHS may be written as
$$4x^2−8x+4\; +\; x^2−2xy+y^2\; +\; y^2−2y+ 1$$
Do you see why this yields the "$\,\ge 0\,$" ?
And also the equality case?

Answer (score 2):

We have: $5x^2 -2xy -8x +2y^2 -2y + 5=\frac{9}{2}(x-1)^2 +\frac{1}{2}(x-2y+1)^2\geqq 0$

Equality holds when $x =y = 1$

Comment: Nice and simple +1

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$5\,x^{\,2}- 2\,xy- 8\,x+ 2\,y^{\,2}- 2\,y+ 5= (\,1+ x- 2\,y\,)(\,5\,x+ 8\,y- 13\,)+ 18(\,y- 1\,)^{\,2}$$
$$9(\,5\,x^{\,2}- 2\,xy- 8\,x+ 2\,y^{\,2}- 2\,y+ 5\,)= -\,(\,1+ x- 2\,y\,)(\,5\,x+ 8\,y- 13\,)+ 2(\,5\,x- y- 4\,)^{\,2}$$
$$\therefore\,5\,x^{\,2}- 2\,xy- 8\,x+ 2\,y^{\,2}- 2\,y+ 5\geqq 0$$
Furthermore
$$\because\,{\rm discriminant}[\,5\,x^{\,2}- 2\,xy- 8\,x+ 2\,y^{\,2}- 2\,y+ 5,\,x\,]= -\,36(\,y- 1\,)^{\,2}\leqq 0$$